# Automatically mount NTFS drive when I login

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, windows-7, automount

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows7 dual boot with Ubuntu as my primary OS.

Every time I need to access a document I need to mount the respective drive, though this is not at all tiresome, still, is there any way that drives becomes automatically mounted when I login?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Notice:** If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 and later, Don't forget to check the note at the end of the answer

---

Go to the Startup Applications, by Clicking right-top corner *Settings* icon ---> *Startup Applications*.

[image]

The click on the Add button, Write a name for this operation such as "Mount ntfs drives",
then in *command* input box, write this `udisks --mount /dev/sda2`, to automount the ntfs partition.

**Note**: You need to replace the `/dev/sda2` with your actual NTFS partition number.

You can get this number by this command:

```
sudo blkid
```

Below is the output of this command in my computer.

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="89b18940-d5ff-4ce1-a85a-42cdd0369016" UUID_SUB="57d79ff6-7b53-44bc-82ec-ef783a23efc3" TYPE="btrfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Main" UUID="A80C1BD70C1B9F7E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Work" UUID="01CCB271A80A07E0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Free" UUID="CA9A-4F0A" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="364126ac-01c9-4dd2-ab19-eecc733a9640" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="Free2" UUID="ed26eebb-524b-4533-869a-9dbd2b92bd64" TYPE="xfs" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="312d4cd9-21a9-4c0d-aa34-26230e70fa89" TYPE="swap"
```

---

**For Mounting with Executable permission**

For those of you (like me) who wants to have executable permission to be set upon mounting, so that you can have options for execute a file with double-clicking , Add this extra bit of options with `udisks` command.

```
--mount-options=umask=022
```

So, the total line for `/dev/sda2` should be like this (tested on 13.04)

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda2 --mount-options=umask=022
```

**Caution:** If you are a bit worried with security, you may choose not to have this functionality.

---

### Note: Change for Ubuntu 14.04 and later

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or newer versions, You may notice that `udisks` packages is no longer available there. Yes, it is replaced by `udisksctl` package. So, You need to use `udisksctl` instead of `udisks`. It is basically do the same things, but syntax is more easier.

#### The mount command is --

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2
```

(in the case your targeted partition is `/dev/sda2`) Here, `-b` is indicating that it is a block device

#### To enable executable permission ---

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2 -o umask=022
```

(Here `-o` indicating that following are options for udisksctl).

You can access the man page of udisksctl with `man udisksctl` command or [read it online here!](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/udisksctl.1.html)

Comment: Is running this command on startup better than adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: If adding to startup works, you don't have to add it in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: I am on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. A couple notes: I had to find startup applications in unity dashboard search. Had to install udisks via command line apt-get install udisks. Afterwards the selected answer method worked fine for me.

Comment: `udisks` is not available in 16.04. It was changed to `/usr/bin/udisksctl`. I believe the apropriate command would be `/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b PATH/TO/DEVICE`.

Comment: @Blazej read the full answer. It was there

Comment: @Anwar My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

The udisks command does the same thing as nautilus

It comes installed by default and doesn't require any changes to your system files.

just add something like:

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/1313-F422
```

to your startup list.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#udisks

Comment: Btw, at least in Xubuntu, it's a bit different: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/THE_UUID`. `udisksctl` is in the `udisks2` package and I don't have a `udisks` package.

Answer (score 7):

I think simply you can add your partition configuration to `/etc/fstab` as well.

Basically get the partition name from command line either through `sudo blkid` or `sudo fdisk -l` SO add to your `/etc/fstab` with `gksu gedit`

The entry should look like this:

`/dev/sd[ab]#    /path_to/mount_point    ntfs-3g    defaults    0 0`

where path to mount point may be something like `/home/YourUserName/Windows`. You may need to `mkdir Windows`. Then you can access windows partition in `Windows` folder inside your `Home` folder

Answer (score 1):

simple - method is to install the pysdm package (in Gutsy) and then use System-Administration-Storage Device Manager without any manual editing of the fstab file, and disregard most of the instructions that follow.

check this site for any doubts

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Answer (score 1):

You could do this directly with the mount command.

Edit /etc/rc.local. This gets executed at startup after boot as root:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and put the mount code inside:

```
mount_at="/media/OS"
partition="/dev/sda3"

if [ ! -d $mount_at ] #create mound directory if it doesn't exist
then
  mkdir $mount_at
fi

mount -t ntfs $partition $mount_at
```

where $mount_at is the folder where you want to mount to, and $partition is the name of the partition. My windows partition is at "/dev/sda3" and not "/dev/sda1" because I have a Dell with other small system partitions. To check what is the name of your windows partition do:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which for me gives

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *      206848    30926847    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30926848   540132512   254602832+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       540133374   625141759    42504193    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       540133376   619132927    39499776   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       619134976   625141759     3003392   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So /dev/sda3 is the largest NTFS partition, probably the one you want.