# Ubuntu 16.04 secodary harddrive is not acessible after login

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have installed secondary 1TB HDD, Ext4 filesystem
It is mounted as

```
/media/USERNAME/ad36cba6-db56-478d-b820-e5cb1e316fc7/....
```

"Automatic mount option" is ON in Disk manager.

But right after I logged in into my OS it is not accessible, path `/media/USERNAME/ad36cba6-db56-478d-b820-e5cb1e316fc7/....`

does not exist.

It becomes accessible ONLY after I get into Files manager and click on its icon.
Then path `/media/USERNAME/ad36cba6-db56-478d-b820-e5cb1e316fc7/....` appearing in command line.

Is it possible to have this path accessible straight after login. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add it to your /etc/fstab?

Comment: No, I don't know what /etc/fstab is. Let me search

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for the tip. Indeed i need to add my hard drive to the fstab. Now its all good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Ubuntu automatically mount a second, internal hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99548/can-ubuntu-automatically-mount-a-second-internal-hard-drive)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make partitions mount at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @user535733 comment I've added my new hard drive to the /etc/fstab. I follower this article:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fstab-automount-hard-drive-linux/

How to make drive accessible right after sign in (log in )

Comment: Please don't ask a question inside the answer. If you want to add new information to the original question, then please edit the original question. If you have a new question please ask a new question.

Comment: If it's correctly added in fstab it is accessible before you login.