# How can i see all my windows files in ubuntu?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically mount NTFS drive when I login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83461/automatically-mount-ntfs-drive-when-i-login)

I just downloaded ubuntu on my computer windows and when i turn it on and get started with Ubuntu I never see any of my files (music, photos, videos) how I can match my windows vista files with ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a dual boot machine, you need to mount the windows partition in ubuntu.

You can have a look in ubuntu docs to see in details how to do that: [ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions). 
Basically you need to identify your windows partition and mount it in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Or.. even easier.. open Nautilus, click the Windows Drive.

Comment: True, but I think this needs to be done at every new boot before using the windows partition in other software (at least this was the case before and I didn't see the change as I registered mine in fstab).

Comment: Pysdm and ntfs-config will save you from editing fstab by hand.}