# Xubuntu: how do I automatically mount external NTFS drive with writes allowed?

Tags: xubuntu, ntfs

I have 2 separate external hard disks, and connect them to a USB port at different times. I would like them to be automatically mounted as read/write.
In fact, I can write new files to them, but cannot then delete the new files I just wrote! Is there a workaround? I read somewhere that etc/fstab doesn't apply to removable media, which are mounted by gnome-volume-manager and therefore cannot be unmounted by a user. How should I proceed in attempting to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically mount NTFS drive when I login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83461/automatically-mount-ntfs-drive-when-i-login)

Comment: Normally, an external partition would be mounted as `rw`, unless there are reasons not to. When was the last time those partitions were checked for errors?

Comment: In kubuntu, it's in system settings->hardware->removable devices.  You can set what to do when connected on boot as well as when plugged in later. Maybe this will point you in the right direction for xubuntu.

Comment: Mmm... In my configuration (standard Xubuntu 12.04 on a Thinkpad x220) my 2 external NTFS USB disks connect automatically with read and write enabled. Are you sure it is not something related to your system (or disks) specifically? Maybe check your disks, Like Mike suggested?

Comment: Access your drive as root and see if it is writable

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Though, Ubuntu should be doing this automatically, provided your drives are healthy.

Plug your drive in.

Use `fdisk -l` to find the name of the external drive. (ie. /dev/sdb)

Unmount the the drive `sudo umount /dev/YOUR_DRIVE_HERE`

Create mount point `sudo mkdir /mnt/MOUNT_POINT`

Mount the drive: `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/YOUR_DRIVE_NAME /mnt/MOUNT_POINT`

More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions#NTFS

Answer (score 1):

You can install ntfs-config which is included in the official repositories. Open a terminal and write:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

And after installing, run it as root:

```
sudo ntfs-config
```

A graphical interface will show up, and after that your NTFS partitions will be automatically mounted every time you boot. There is an option to enable write support in there too.