# Storage partition: mount point during installation or later?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop.

I decided to create a logical partition to store my big files (music, videos, pictures...) somewhere else than the `home` folder, so I created this partition **during the new Ubuntu installation process** in ext4 format, using the mount-point `/data`. I'll later try to redirect my `Pictures`, `Videos` and `Documents` from `/home` in this `/data` folder, using symbolic links.

However, I just read [an article](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.it/2009/11/howto-setup-linux-storage-partition.html) that explains how to create a storage partition **after Ubuntu installation**, using GParted to mount the unused space on a `/mnt/storage` folder (for example).

What's the difference between these two methods, and what do you think is the best to follow?

Comment: This is not an answer, but just a recommendation that you might want to use [binds](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249196/whats-the-best-way-to-add-native-looking-links-to-my-ntfs-data-partition) rather that symbolic links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you link to the article, so we can see exactly what is explained?

Anyway, I would recommend to set up all the partitons during the install, then everything is taken care of with gparted and `/etc/fstab` is correct - you do not have to edit it manually afterwards. Other than that, creating a partition is the same, no technical difference between doing it during or after installing the OS.

**Edit:** After reading the article, it does not change anything, really. When you create your partition does not matter, but doing it after the installation will create extra manual work (which you can mess up :-))

And as a comment above noted: Instead of using symbolic links, you may want to [mount the partitions with bind](http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts).

Comment: I updated my question adding the article link :)

Comment: And I updated the answer!