# How to configure Ubuntu to load shared hard disk at startup?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, firefox, startup

I use shared profile for firefox between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. The shared profile is in a common disk partition/file-system. Due to this reason firefox doesn't start till I load the shared hard disk in Ubuntu.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed inside Windows-7 using wubi. The shared drive I am talking about is actually the other disk partitions in Windows.

I wanted to know how to configure Ubuntu so that it automatically loads the shared disk partition/file-system at startup?

---

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83461/automatically-mount-ntfs-drive-when-i-login). My result for

```
sudo blkid
```

is

```
/dev/loop0: UUID="4b7302d4-3802-433e-8208-2cbd0a0c2ea1" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtility" UUID="5450-4444" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="3E3A243D3A23F097" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="F25608385607FFD9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="5AB27043B2702623" TYPE="ntfs"
```

How do I find which of these to use in the startup command?

---

I have absolutely no idea which of the above 5 have the firefox profile. I know it is in `E:` drive in Windows 7. In Ubuntu it is shown as `141 GB file system` and at the top a number `5AB2704` something is present. How to find out which of the above 5 is the file-system that I want.

Comment: @mikewhatever Not really. I have only 1 hard drive.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Well, you mount a file system anyway, or, in other words, a partition. People confusingly call these 'drives' - not the best terminology IMHO. You can get the list of partition by running the `sudo fdisk -l` command.

Comment: @mikewhatever My bad. Updated the question again with some more info.

Comment: Which one has the firefox profile?

Comment: @mikewhatever Updated the question again.

Comment: Looks like it's /dev/sda5. Its UUID is "5AB27043B2702623".

Comment: @mikewhatever It worked. Make that an answer