# Changing current directory to shared filesytem using linux terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, filesystem

I have a shared filesystem (E: in my installation of Windows 7) in which I keep my programming codes. I want to shift from Windows to Ubuntu for programming mainly because I like the linux terminal compared to alternative in Windows.

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325747/how-to-configure-ubuntu-to-load-shared-hard-disk-at-startup) question after which I came to know that my shared filesystem is `/dev/sda5`. I tried to use terminal to `cd` to this directory but I wasn't able to do so.

I have the shared filesystem loaded and I was in `/dev` when I tried to change to `sda5`. The error was

> bash: cd: sda5: Not a directory

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it mounted in somewhere. The device is there but you have no access to it to achieve this you must use the [mount](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm) command. First create a mounting point as:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/shared
```

Then you can mount the sda5 to it:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5 /mnt/shared
```

Now, your files should be in `/mnt/shared`:

```
cd /mnt/shared
```

I don't encourage you to do so cause it can harm files having different end line encodings in windows / linux. What I suggest you is to create another partition and move the files you want to use on both systems there. Then stick with a multi OS IDE.

Comment: Can I mount only a particular folder from the drive there? The reason I cannot keep it in Ubuntu is because it is installed inside Windows and my computer doesn't have good enough configuration to have 2 separate OS.

Comment: @AseemBansal Sure you can all you have to do is specify the whole path of the directory i.e: 
`sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5/blah /mnt/shared`
Where blah is the specific folder you want to mount.
 . Notice that mount does not use twice as much space in the disk as you mentioned cause all the command do it to enable the files in disk to access from the OS.

Comment: So the only things I have in the directory are simple .C files, git files and simple windows folders then that wouldn't mess up line encodings. Correct or that can mess up things even in this case like you said?

Comment: @AseemBansal line ends can be messed up in text files. As I've mentioned if you are consistent with the IDE you are using in both systems it will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the partition.

Create a directory where you want to mount it. `mkdir ~/programCode`

Then mount the partition there `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda5 ~/programCode`

`cd ~/programCode` and you files should be there