# How can I undo ntfs-config changes and mount my hard drive correctly?

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs

Alright, forgive me but I just started using linux yesterday and am having a hell of a time trying to set it up how I want.

I need a folder on my second hard drive to be able to be read/written to by anyone, but for whatever reason the permissions would revert as soon as I tried to set them. Frustrated, I blindly tried to use the ntfs configuration tool thinking it would do what I want but it ended up just locking me out of everything and changing the owner to root (which I cannot set back even after trying to delete the fstab entries)

So my questions are

1. How do I change back what ntfs-config did so I can be the owner of my own drive again?
2. How can I set my ntfs partition as completely read-writable by anyone when chmod and chown fail me?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Undo ntfs-config's changes

ntfs-config saves backup of your previous `fstab` file with name `fstab-ntfs-config-save`. So, to revert the entries, you need to use this command in terminal

```
sudo mv /etc/fstab-ntfs-config-save /etc/fstab
```

#### Mounting NTFS with read/write permission

By default, Ubuntu allow you to mount ntfs with read/write permission. That should be enough. If you want to automount it during login check this question [Automatically mount NTFS drive when I login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83461/automatically-mount-ntfs-drive-when-i-login/156607#156607) (*Disclaimer: There is an answer from me*)

Also note that, if you already mounted a partition as for example say, **User1** you can't mount it again using **User2**. You need to first unmount it using **User1** then **User2** can mount it.

Comment: You actually don't need that disclaimer... You are not promoting a product here. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I know :) But I was feeling, I must write an answer containing that _Disclaimer_ thing. ha ha